# How to run VLC command in mac terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, vlc-media-player

I am trying to crop a number of videos using the following vlc terminal command:

```
vlc input.mp4 --crop=480x270+200+100
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
-bash: vlc: command not found
```

How can I run a vlc command in mac terminal?

Comment: Do you have vlc installed? If yes, probably the vlc binary is not in your path and you need to use the full path to vlc in your scripts.

Answer (score 37):

Use the following command to set vlc as an alias:

```
alias vlc='/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC'
```

You can then use `vlc input.mp4` to play a video.

The above path is for Mac OS. If you are using another system, just change the path for VLC accordingly.

Comment: See also official wiki for video lan client (vlc) https://wiki.videolan.org/MacOS/#Command_line

Comment: Interesting, why symbolic link approach doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, as recommended here [on this gist](https://gist.github.com/kgriffs/6393192), you can add the following in an executable file called `vlc` in your `/usr/local/bin` folder:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -I rc "$@"
```

Make the file executable using `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/vlc`. At this this point, typing `vlc` in the terminal should give you VLC's command line functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
$ open -a VLC 'videopath.mp4'
```

will also work on the MacOS command line